# Rails: refactoring chained where clauses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What's best practice to rewrite something like this? I find it way too cumbersome:

```
def filtered_components(template)
  components.joins(:templates).where(templates: { id: template.id }).where(state: 'working').where(['fake_created_at < ?', Time.now]).order('created_at DESC')
end
```

There's gotta be a better way, right?

Thanks.

Comment: the first two `where`s can just be combined together into one. The string condition can't though, without turning the whole thing into a string condition.

Comment: @emm: Please, remember to mark as accepted the question that most helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part **ActiveRecord** caters to the common use cases.  For anything complex, you're going to end up chaining lots of filters together.

```
# Combined where clauses to slightly reduce complexity

def filtered_components(template)
  components.joins(:templates).where(["template_id = ? AND state = ? AND fake_created_at < ?", template.id, 'working', Time.now]).order('created_at DESC')
end
```

Also, depending on your situation, you might not need `template_id` in your `where` clause.  If you're joining `:templates` onto `:components`, ActiveRecord will translate that to:

```
INNER JOIN "templates" ON "templates".component_id = "components".id
```

Answer (score 3):

I would have just one where clause

```
def filtered_components(template)
  components.joins(:templates).where("templates.id = ? AND components.state = ? AND components.fake_created_at < ?", template.id, 'working', Time.now).order('created_at DESC')
end
```

Looks clear for me.